# Regular Expression Directory

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a directory path that begins with `/en/` or ends with `=en`.

I try this one :

```
(/en/|=en)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Check `^` and `$` regex metacharacters. `^` (or `\A`) is the beginning of string, `$` (or `\z`) is the end of string.

Comment: On which language do you need this regex? That's a significant information

Comment: (^\/en\/|=en$) would work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the forward slashes and add in the anchors ^ and $

```
(^\/en\/|=en$)
```

Comment: Ha, beat you to it. ;) have a +1 anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to make it -  /(^\/en\/|=en$)/g

Comment: For that particular one vittore posted you'd have to add the m flag to make it multiline as well.

Comment: @JohnClifford that would be completely different regex, you should not do multiline.